# Magento 2 : Currency Symbol missing when exporting Saler Order Grid

Tags: magento-2.1, export, magento-2.1.9, order-grid

I am exporting **Magento 2.1.9** Saler Order Grid to **CSV and XML** formats using the provided buttons. But when I open the file in Excel the currency symbol is missing in **Grand Total (Base)** and **Grand Total (Purchased)** columns.

I need the currency symbols in all price colums when exporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is what I did to achieve the desired output.

- Created a new Module and override the Convert Classes (ConvertToCsv / ConvertToXml) from `vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Export/`
- Replaced following code

---

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($item, $component->getName());
    $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getRowData($item, $fields, $options));
}
```

With

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // Add currency
    $item['base_grand_total'] = $item['base_currency_code'].$item['base_grand_total'];
    $item['grand_total'] = $item['order_currency_code'].$item['grand_total'];
    $item['subtotal'] = $item['base_currency_code'].$item['subtotal'];
    $item['shipping_and_handling'] = $item['base_currency_code'].$item['shipping_and_handling'];

    $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($item, $component->getName());
    $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getRowData($item, $fields, $options));
}
```

It did the trick for me - hope someone will find it useful or someone will provide a better solution.